# How to get a Jenkins slave to open a windows server session

Tags: jenkins, windows-server-2003, jenkins-plugins, qtp, gui-testing

I'm trying to get a Jenkins slave to open a session on a windows server.
Basically, What I'm try to achieve is:

- Jenkins slave is running as a service on a windows 2003 server. When master calls slave, it will open a desktop session on the server and kick off an .exe that will perform GUI testing

What I have done:

- Jenkins node created (Node A). Dumb slave. Remote FS root set to path on Windows 2003 server. ("C:\Jenkins\Node"). Launch method Java Web Start
- Slave 'Node A' installed from Jenkins master using Java Web Start on windows 2003 server
- Jenkins slave now running as a service on server
- Jenkins project created and 'Restrict where this project can be run' is set to 'Node A'

  - Project windows batch command 'C:\GUITest.exe'

When I build the project in Jenkins I was expecting that the slave would be able to open a session and run C:\GUITest.exe. But, I'm missing something.

Anyone any ideas, or know if it is possible (plugins I may need ??)

Any advise / direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to run GUI test on windows session. It won't work if you run Jenkins Slave as service, you have to run JNLP agent on your windows server. Also if you want to run in unattended mode, meaning that the windows remote session would be disconnected, you need some other setup as well. Please provide more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Andy,What I'm trying to do is: Setup a Jenkins job to run an exe on a server session that is not yet active. So, I need the slave to be running on the server, and once the job is run / scheduled from the master, the slave will open a desktop sessions and run the exe. I have tried simple things like a job to run C:\winnt\notepad.exe. i run the job from the master, and i can see the slave has kicked off notepad.exe on the server, but i need it to be in an open session with a desktop.

Comment: And yes - the purpose of this is for Automated GUI testing. I want the slave to open up a desktop session on the server (as the GUI tool needs a desktop) and run GUITest.exe - this exe will in turn open up my AUT and run the GUI test. Any ideas of how to achieve this ?? (I hope this makes sense, if not ask for more details please!)

Comment: Run something on Master is different on slaves. I don't know if you can dynamically open remote sessions on slaves. Usually we just log on the Slave windows, launch the slave agent, then you could run your GUI tests. This assumes that all your tests could be run on that single slave.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that whatever process runs the GUI tests (might be a java / cmd / ssh process if you're connected to Jenkins) is not running on session 0 as it won't have access to Desktop and the Windows UI in general. I was in a similar situation and running the same process as a scheduled task instead of service solved it for me.